# Unsubscribe link is not working in magento newsletter template

Tags: magento

I have created one newsletter template in my store ( magento based ) and have added following code to make unsubscribe link:

Follow this link to unsubscribe:

{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}

But, when I tested it there was no link received in my email. I can see only "Follow this link to unsubscribe:" in my email but there is no link to unsubscribe this email.

Note: I have added this content under "Template Content" section.

Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your Template.php file the getTemplateText function should look something similar to this;

```
public function getTemplateText()
{
    if (!$this->getData('template_text') && !$this->getId()) {
        $this->setData('template_text',
            Mage::helper('newsletter')->
            __('Follow this link to unsubscribe <!-- This tag is for unsubscribe link  -->
            <a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">
            {{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}</a>')
        );
    }

    return $this->getData('template_text');
}
```

Is this what you are using? It could be that the  tags have been removed.

You should also check what happens when the emails are sent to different mail clients, just to rule out local factors.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late here but still I want to share solution here.

I am using Magento 1.9.
To add newsletter unsubscribe link in newsletter template here are following steps:

1. Override the core file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

by copy in local directory

> /app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

2. Open in editor to edit the code and seacrh the `function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()`
   replace the code

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this)
);
```

with this

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this, 'unsubscribe' =>$this->getUnsubscriptionLink())
);
```

3. and place this code in email template where you want to use unsubscribe link:

   `<a href="{{var unsubscribe}}">Unsubscribe here</a>`

That's it!

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.

Comment: Sorry @kleopatra for this inconvenience , Actually I found same question with no accepted answer when I was search for the same issue. afterword I found the issue and feel that I should share my solution with all post. That's why I have post same answer on multiple post

Comment: if you find the same question, please vote/flag to close the duplicate :-)